# How to add multiple c# file in single console project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

Hey I am new to c# programming I had created a new console app in C# using vs code terminal and it gives a some files and one program.cs file where my program can write. What should I do to create another .cs file and run it the same project

Comment: What has this question got to do with ASP.NET? What has it got to do with C# 4 specifically? It's about VS Code yet you haven't added that tag. Please put some thought into your tags and apply all that are relevant and none that are not.

Answer (score 2):

**In Visual Studio:** 
Right Click your project > Add > New Class

**In Visual Studio Code:** 
In the explorer, where it says your project/folder name, there's a tiny document icon with a `+` icon on it
Click that, type the name of your new file - ensuring it ends with `.cs`.
You should now have a new file in your project

Answer (score 2):

Literally just create a text file called `Whatever.cs` and start typing; as long as it is inside the same folder structure as the project file (including sub-folders) and has the extension `.cs`, it will be included in the build automatically.